# weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstanceInvocationHandler NullPointerException

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, weblogic

We got NPE

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.java:172)
```

We use WebLogic wls12.2.1.3.0-190716 on jdk8u221

This happens in one of our environments, all the other environments use the same setup and it works.
Enabling DEBUG doesn't help, no additional logs at this point.
We have log with the whole SOAP request prepared and then NPE. Request is correct - checked in other env.

Comment: We reinstalled everything as in last comment:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=0b961194-edb0-4a18-aef3-82ee89f7b98d&ps=50

And the same result..

Comment: Anything in Standard Out / Standard Error logs? 
Generally if any NPE has stack of product itself then it can be a bug. But as it's working fine in other environments we can rule out the product issue here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long investigation we discovered that our wsdl file were lacking from deployment package resulting in NPE error.
WSDL was definied in Spring @WebServiceClient.
Null was passed to Weblogic lib through proxy interfaces.

Anyway thanks for help :)